# Convert algorithm from o(n) to o(1)

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, optimization, division

Basically what I wanted to is if a number `n` is divisible by `b` for `a`(count) times, then find the `a`(count), and divide `n` by `b` for `a`(count) times.

That is,

```
count = 0;
while(n%b == 0)
    n=n/b;
    count = count + 1;
```

How to optimize this, so that everything can be obtained in one step

Comment: You meant `n=n/b;` ?

Comment: You mean find for numbers n and m, whether `logₘn` is a round number?

Comment: @RealSkeptic No, given `n=b^a * M`, he's looking for `a`, without importance to value of `M`.

Comment: OK, so find `logₘn`, round it down, then divide by the power?

Comment: @RealSkeptic No, n=62, b=2, as AlexeiShestakov  suggested when I misunderstood the question as well. Note that by definition you can also get a=0 when `n%b != 0` in the first place.

Comment: @AlexeiShestakov I meant n = n/b , sorry all for the mistake

Comment: @RealSkeptic can you explain the log answer ? is it a correct approach ?

Comment: Mine? No, Amit explained what you meant, so my approach will not give you the correct solution. His will give you the correct solution, but it's not O(1). Are you sure there is supposed to be an O(1) solution to this question?

Comment: would like to have an o(1) answer if possible.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in `O(log(a))` by applying binary search, on a sorted "list" to find the last element that equals 1.

The list is metaphoric, and each element in it is calculated on the fly when queried by a simple calculation:

```
list[i] = 1      n % a^i == 0
          0      otherwise
```

You can first find the range of possible `a`'s using exponention:

```
curr = b
tempA = 1
while n % curr == 0:
    curr = curr  * curr
    tempA = tempA *2
```

And then, run the binary search on the range `[tempA/2, tempA]`. This range is of size `(a/2)`, so finding the last "element" that the symbolic list holds `1` - is done in `O(loga)` multiplications.

Code + Demo:

```
private static int specialBinarySearch(int n, int b, int aLow, int aHigh) {
    if (aHigh == aLow) return aHigh;
    int mid = (aHigh - aLow)/2 + aLow;
    //pow method can be optimized to remember pre-calculated values and use them
    int curr = (int)Math.round(Math.pow(b, mid));
    if (n % curr == 0) { //2nd half, or found it:
        if (n % (curr*b) != 0) return mid; //found it
        return specialBinarySearch(n, b, mid+1, aHigh); //2nd half
    }
    else return specialBinarySearch(n, b, aLow, mid); //first half

}

public static int findA(int n, int b) { 
    int curr = b;
    int tempA = 1;
    while (n % curr == 0) {
        curr = curr  * curr;
        tempA = tempA *2;
    }
    return specialBinarySearch(n, b, tempA/2, tempA);
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(findA(62,2)); //1
    System.out.println(findA(1024,2)); //10
    System.out.println(findA(1,2)); //0
    System.out.println(findA(100,2)); //2
    System.out.println(findA(6804,3)); //5

}
```

Comment: In this case, I would prefer the brute-force approach for its simplicity, which already runs in a reasonable `O(log(n))`.

Comment: @Lingxi This is `O(log(a)) = O(log(log(n))`.

Comment: Did you benchmark this code vs the original? I'd expect it runs quite a lot slower than the original code (which has as its worst case 31 divides and mods in a tight loop).

Comment: @Anonymous (1) OP asks to reduce time complexity as denoted by big O (to O(1), but I dont think that's possible), and the code indeed do it, reducing it from `O(logn)` integer arithmetics to `O(loglog(n))` (2) this code needs 15 mods and no divides (except divide by 2, which is easy) at worst case for n<2^31, and can be optimize to need only 10 for worst case, by removing the "foundIt" part and instead including the mid in the "right"  part of the recursive call. (3) You can further optimize this code for constants using tail recursion and smarter pow method that uses already calculated values

Comment: @Anonymous (4) try to run it for integers larger than `int` size, and I am certain you will see improvement, as it will run in `O(loglog(n)*M(log(n))`, and naive approach in `O(log(n)*M(log(n))` - where M(.) is the complexity for divide/multiply/mod, as function of number of bits in the number.

Comment: (If I was not clear, this solution aims to show algorithm with better complexity in terms of big O notation, as the OP asked, and neglects constants. I did add some suggestions to improve constants, but I did not handle with it at all, this is not the goal of the answer, and this is not what the question is asking).

Comment: @amit yes, if you think of this is a question about algorithmic complexity, then your answer is fine. It was tagged "java", "c++" and "optimization" though, which makes me less certain than you are it's theoretical.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot solve this in O(1) but there is a different kind of approach to this problem if you start using a numeric system where `b` is the base.

For example, if we have a number like 154200, and `b` is 10, we know the answer is 2 here immediately because we can simply count how many zeros there are on the right hand side.

Similarly, in binary, if `b` is 2, you simply count how many zeros there are on the right side with a binary representation.

If `b` is 5, we have to use the odd base 5 representation where a number like 8 is represented as 13. Again we know that the answer for `a` is zero is `n=8` and `b=5` because there are no zeros on the right hand side.

This won't necessarily give you speed gains except possibly in cases where `b` is a power of two where you can use bitwise logic to deduce the answer, but it gives you a different kind of way of looking at the problem lexically by digits instead of through arithmetic.